# How to add where condition in hook_views_query_alter with a join

Tags: views

I have a files listing view which I need to filter on the basis of current logged in user's roles. Since one user can have multiple roles I want to filter data on the basis of all the roles those are assigned to current logged in user. I used following code but it didn't work.

How do I achieve this?

here is the code that I wrote:

```
function ModuleName_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){
  global $user;
  if ($view->name == 'my_view_name'){
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    $view->query->add_where($user->roles,$user_roles,'IN');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this.

```
function ModuleName_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){
  if ($view->name == "my_view_name") {
     $join = new views_join;
     $join->construct('TABLE NAME', 'NODE', 'nid', 'entity_id', '', 'LEFT');

     $view->query->add_relationship('TABLE NAME', $join, 'node');
     $query->add_where('TABLE NAME', 'TABLE NAME.FIELD NAME', FILTER VALUE, 'IN');
  }
```

You Can Use your entity type in this function, i used NODE here. I hope this helps you.

Don't forget to mark it right if this help you ;)